# How to read an age into double

Tags: c++

I am learning programming using "Programming,principles and practice using C++ by Stroustrup".I have to read a person's age into double and display it in months.Now my confusion is when a person enters an age for example: 22.5, should it be considered 22 years and 5 months or 22 years 6 months since it is .5?
How to separate 22 and 5 to two different integers from the double?

Comment: Why would you want to split the integers?

Comment: To convert into months,I want to multiply years into 12 and add the decimal part.

Comment: It is up to you to decide how `22.5` should be interpreted. Just make sure that you document it clearly and take care of corner cases.

Comment: Some possible corner cases would be if `22.1` is not the same as `22.10`, and what `22.11` would mean.

Answer (score 1):

Think about it: you're asking for age in *years*. So 22.5 years should be considered 22 years and 6 months.

Answer (score 1):

22.5 years is 22 years + 0.5 year. 0.5 year = 6 months.

This should work for you:

```
int years = floor(age);         // get the integer part of age -- that's years
double frac = age - years;      // get the fractional part of age
int months = round(12. * frac); // convert the fractional part into # of months
```

Comment: @GeorgeSkopstov: The OP is learning from a book, so it might not be a good idea to just spoon-feed answers and have the OP not understand it.

Comment: Agree in general, but in this case the answer to his question would necessarily involve `floor` and `round`. Now he should be able to look up the functions and understand the answer. One problem I see is that he may have more trouble with the math part of the answer than with the coding part

Comment: Agreed. But if the OP has trouble with the concept of `22.5 years == 22 years + 6 months` the OP will have a difficult time with coding in general.

Comment: I'm not sure that this meets the requirements.  What he seems to be asking for is the age in months, given the age in years.  No need for any conversions to `int` or calls to `floor`.

Comment: Well, he wanted to know how to extract the fractional part out as an integer -- this is the only way that makes sense to me. I now see that he thinks that whatever follows the decimal point should be the number of months. In any case, it's for the best: he's got everything he needs (and more) in this answer, and we haven't spoon-fed it to him.